# Get total count of json keys and objects in PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a Json with this structure: ( attached image ) 
I want total keys in 0,1,11 overall.

I have this code that gives me the output "3" but i want the total objects in those 3 objects overall:

```
$url = '//json url';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
echo count($data['planes']);
```

[Json Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn7Ql.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

<s>In Javascript, count the object's keys:</s>

```
Object.keys(myObj).length
```

Or, in PHP, convert it to an array and count it:

```
$json = json_decode($myStr);
count($json);
```

You can access members of the `$json` array with numeric indices and `count()` them, or decode them again, etc:

```
echo count($json[2])
```

Pass `true` to `json_decode()` to create an associative array (which you must access using string keys, not numeric indices).

Comment: In **PHP 7.2+**, you will need to pass `true` in second argument for `json_decode` to return a array. The `count()` function will emit a **_E_WARNING_** for non-countable types, and `new stdclass` not implements Countable interface. ([See in the doc.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration72.incompatible.php))

Answer (score 0):

use Object.keys() method. It returnes array of all keys in object, then use length method to get array length

for example

```
var x = {
    0: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    },
    1: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    },
    1: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    },
}

var total = 0;
for( var obj in x ) {
    total += Object.keys(x[obj]).length ;
}
```